# C3js - combination chart with data labels only for line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I want to create a combination chart with stacked bars + line using c3js. I don't want to see data labels on top of the stacked bars but I want to see them for the line. 
I know that flag "labels: true/false" is showing/hiding ALL the labels.
Is it even possible to do something like this?

My code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 20, 50, 40, 60, 50],
            ['data2', 200, 130, 90, 240, 130, 220],
            ['data3', 100, 230, 390, 440, 230, 120],
            ['line4', 430, 480, 630, 820, 450, 490]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        types: {
            line4: 'line'
        },
        groups: [
            ['data1','data2', 'data3']
        ],
        labels: true
    }
});
```

## Chart created:

[image: Chart created by me]

## Desired Chart:

[image: Desired chart]

Answer (score 2):

You can though set data label *formatting* per data series:

```
    labels: {
        format: {
            data3: d3.format(),
        }
    }
```

..and it seems omitting a format for a data series means the labels aren't drawn for that series.

http://jsfiddle.net/wn3vzn0k/424/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved it. It's exactly what I was hoping for. 

But it's also strange how I missed this page: [c3js data_label_format](http://c3js.org/samples/data_label_format.html)

Comment: yeh, i should have added that link because that example is what I used in the jsfiddle (made one a line just to see if it made a difference)